# Android Deeplinking Multiple Host Support

Tags: android, deep-linking

How to support android deeplinking multiple host.

Sample

```
x.com/dummy
y.com/dummy

https://x.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
https://y.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

Could such a use exist?